# Missing face.hpp in OpenCV 3.1.0 after successful build with opencv_contrib modules

Tags: c++, cmake, opencv3.1

I am doing a project in C++ using OpenCV and stuck with adding face recognition module

I have built without errors the Extra modules of OpenCV (opencv_contrib) using the following make commands

```
$ cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../opencv_contrib/modules ../opencv-3.1.0  
$ make 
$ sudo make install
```

My code involves the following as I copied the code for testing

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/face.hpp"        //-----> Doesn't exist
```

This shows the following error when I attempt building the code in code::blocks :

```
~/Desktop/OpenCV_Project/OpenCv_Demos/Face_Recognition/main.cpp|6|fatal error: opencv2/face.hpp: No such file or directory|
```

I have searched the linked directories too, there is no file as face.hpp

How do I ensure that the extra modules were really built with openCV source after make/make install?

Other requisites:
Ubuntu 15.10
Code::blocks 16.10
gcc version 5.2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently I managed to solve the issue by doing the following.

1.Navigate to opencv_contrib/modules directory and copy face folder
2.Navigate to opencv-3.1.0/module directory and paste.
3.Make a build folder (or wherever to build) and execute the following make command.

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE  ..
```

i.e. without the extra modules (since we already copied the required module in opencv-3.1.0/modules)

4.Then

```
make
sudo make install
```

I wonder whats the shortcoming of this method and why it isn't documented anywhere.